# Google sheets add on do not show menu items for all sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-workspace, google-apps-script-addon

So I just published an Google Sheets add-on.

It shows the menu items for the first sheet. But as soon as I run some functions on that sheet, it only shows menu items on that sheet and not the other sheets in my drive.

I think that addon script is getting bound to the first sheet somehow.

Any ideas why it would be happening?

Comment: Addition - If I go to manage add ons on any other sheet, select manage for the add-on for this sheet then it allows me to use the add-on on the differnt sheet.

Comment: Close your spreadsheets and open them again.

Comment: Nope, does not work.

Comment: Please add more details. Is your add-on publicly available, unlisted or private? Is this your first add-on? Have you successfully published and add-on sample before? Is your add on a standalone project or bounded project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the add-on was publically published. 
I figured it out. It was because of an error in the global variable declaration - 
activeSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSreadsheet();

Your add-ons have a google console project associated with them. The console gives access to error reporting. I found this error on the console. I corrected the error and published it and now it is working fine.